# About Morita equivalent and regular block of category $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}$

Tags: weights, kazhdan-lusztig

In the following paper: **Representation type of the blocks of category $\mathcal{O}_S$**
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870804002853

On p.196, it states that "When $\mu$ is regular we may write $\mathcal{O}^{\text{reg}}_S$ for $\mathcal{O}^{\mu}_S$; by Translation Principle these blocks are all Morita equivalent."

In the book "**Symmetry: Representation Theory and Its Applications**", p.144. The Translation Principle is called "Jantzen-Zuckerman translation principle".

What is meant by Morita equivalent here?

The parabolic Kazhdan-Lustzig-Vogan polynomials is defined on section 3.4 of the paper: **Kostant modules in blocks of category $\mathcal{O}_S$**.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0604336.pdf
${}^SP_{x,w}(q):=\sum_{i\ge 0}q^{\frac{\ell(x,w)-i}{2}}\dim\text{Ext}_{\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}}(N_x,L_w)$ where $N_x,L_w$ is defined in section 2.2-2.3.

Does Morita equivalent implies that ${}^SP_{x,w}(q)$ is independent of the choice of regular antidominant weight $\mu$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why they use the term 'Morita equivalent' here, the point is that the blocks are equivalent categories. Since the categories are equivalent, $\newcommand{\Ext}{\mathop{\rm Ext}\nolimits}\dim\Ext_{\mathcal{O}^{\mathfrak{p}}}(N_x, L_y)$ is the same regardless of which category you work in, so yes, $^SP_{x, w}(q)$ is independent of the choice of regular antidominant weight $\mu$.

Comment: Does you mean if there is an equivalence of categories bewteen $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}_\lambda$ and $\mathcal{O}^\mathfrak{p}_\mu$ implies generalized Verma module with highest weight $\lambda$ maps to generalized Verma module with highest weight $\mu$ and similar for the simple modules?

Comment: Yes, same with projectives and injectives. The equivalence $\mathcal{O}_\lambda^{\mathfrak{p}}\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_\mu^{\mathfrak{p}}$ maps $P^{\mathfrak{p}}(w\cdot\lambda)\mapsto P^{\mathfrak{p}}(w\cdot\mu)$, $I^{\mathfrak{p}}(w\cdot\lambda)\mapsto I^{\mathfrak{p}}(w\cdot\mu)$, $L(w\cdot\lambda)\mapsto L(w\cdot\mu)$, etc.

Comment: Translation functors are explained in Chapter 7 of Humphreys' "Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category $\mathcal{O}".

Comment: @JamesCheung I am not sure that equivalence implies it. But it is true.

Comment: @JohanKåhrström Do you have a reference for this implication?

Comment: @VítTuček Which implication do you mean?

Comment: @JohanKåhrström The implication that James Cheung asked about. I.e. if we have an equivalence between two infinitesimal blocks of $\mathcal{O}$, then the equivalence maps $L(w\cdot \lambda) \mapsto L(w\cdot \mu)$ etc.

Comment: @VítTuček Humphreys' "Representations of Semisimple Lie Algebras in the BGG Category O", Chapter 7. Specifically section 7.6 for simple and Verma modules, and Section 7.11 for projective modules. Note that the chapter doesn't cover the parabolic case, but the equivalence $\mathcal{O}_\lambda\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_\mu$ restricts to an equivalence $\mathcal{O}_\lambda^{\mathfrak{p}}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_\mu^{\mathfrak{p}}$ with similar properties.

Comment: @JohanKåhrström But in that book these equivalences are actually proved by first examining what happens for Vermas and simples. The question here is whether we can prove that if there is an equivalence of infinitesimal blocks then it respects the Weyl ordering and sends appropriate Vermas to Vermas and simples to simples.

Comment: I interpreted the question as 'if there is an equivalence induced by translation functors', in which case it is true. I don't know if it is true for _any_ equivalence, but would imagine it is not so. I believe (but may be wrong) that any automorphism $\sigma$ of the Weyl group would induce a corresponding auto-equivalence of a block. Such an equivalence would still map simples to simples, Vermas to Vermas, etc., but $L(w\cdot\lambda)$ would map to $L(\sigma(w)\cdot\lambda)$.

Answer (score 0):

From the introduction: *Cline et al. [CPS] introduced the concept of quasi-hereditary algebras in connection with their study of highest weight categories in 1988. In this paper they proved that a highest weight category is equivalent to the module category for some quasi-hereditary algebra*

So when they speak about Morita equivalence they are talking about two quasi-hereditary algebras whose categories of modules are the blocks of $\mathcal{O}$. (I presume. I am not familiar with Cline's work. Is it true that Morita equivalence implies equivalence of categories of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules?)

Comment: These categories of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules are equivalent to the categories of modules for the algebras, so if the algebras are Morita equivalent, then the categories of $\mathfrak{g}$-modules are equivalent.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Of course. I don't know what I was thinking.